# How to upgrade Xcode 3.1.2 to Xcode 4.4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, xcode4.3

New to iOS, Have downloadex xcode 4.3.3 ie: xcode_4.3.3_for_lion.dmg,  already the Xcode is present in this machine of the version 3.1.2 [ which i get from spotlight].

Question:
If i want new Xcode 4.3.3, then all i need to double click on xcode_4.3.3_for_lion.dmg, and then click on Xcode.

How can i make Xcode 4.3.3 is a default version, and remove the old 3.1.2 version?.

Answer (score 2):

Before installation of Xcode 4 open terminal

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

This will uninstall Xcode 3. Then you can install Xcode 4 as always

Comment: sudo: /Developer-old/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found. Any library do i need to install?

Comment: I recommend you to download and install xcode4.4 from Mac Appstore as encouraged by Apple. In future, you could one click update of xcode. Also when you installing new version, it would prompt you to remove old version of xcode

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the manual download.  Open the Mac App Store, install Xcode from there.  When you run it for the first time, it should prompt you to remove the old version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the version installed in your mac. Then do one easy thing mentioned in below image

[image]

Enjoy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove and reinstalled somehow.. :(